# SQL query verification - simple

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to write a query to find the 2nd oldest girl student in a class
DOB is date of birth as time stamp
name and gender are varchar

```
SELECT min(DOB)
FROM Student
WHERE DOB > (SELECT min(DOB) FROM Student where gender='girl')
```

Is this correct?

Comment: You'd need the 'gender=girl' criteria in your first query.

Answer (score 2):

Or simpler:

```
SELECT DOB
FROM Student
WHERE gender='girl'
GROUP BY DOB
ORDER BY DOB ASC
LIMIT 1,1
```

Grouping by DOB means that two identical DOBs (twins?) that the next lowest is select. It can be omitted in a second identical date counts as the second oldest.

Comment: I think when DOB same for the student may give wrong result right?

Comment: good point. added grouping. Also affects `ROW_NUMBER()` solutions

Answer (score 0):

The below query will provide you the desired output

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DOB ) AS Rnk
FROM Student
WHERE gender='girl'
)
SELECT min(DOB)
FROM T
WHERE Rnk = 2;
```

You can change the RNK value to get the next oldest value, say for third oldest you can use `WHERE Rnk = 3`

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH myTableWithRows AS (
    SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY   Student.DOB)) as row,*
    FROM Student )
    SELECT * FROM myTableWithRows WHERE  row = 2
```

I created this fake example and the query result is the following:

[image: Table and query result]

Or alternatively you can use this query:

```
 Select top 1 * from (select top 2 from    Student order by dob desc) order by dob desc
```

Comment: I am using T-SQL 2014. I made up an example for verification.

Comment: but the question is for mysql - so if the OP uses mysql version above 8.0 then your query may work otherwise not

Comment: I am seeing SQL and database tags as well! In the question, it is mentioned SQL! I don't know if it will run in mySQL though. I am hopeful it helps.

Comment: but your answer is db specific not such which will work in every database :)

Comment: I am not that advance! :D